# Check if marker is in view (map) - mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

[image]I want to check if marker is on mapview or out of the map.
I am putting marker of the map and not able to check if it on currentView or not. I have tried below code. 
     this.map.getBounds().contains(e.layer.getLatLng());
but it is returning me true.
map is returning its old lat lng i.e bounds (I think so)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`map.getBounds().contains(myMarker.getLatLng())`

- [`map.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds): Returns the LatLngBounds of the current map view.
- [`latLngBounds.contains()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains): Returns `true` if the rectangle contains the given point.
- [`myMarker.getLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-getlatlng): Returns the current geographical position of the marker.

See also: [area estimation in viewpoint of map using leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628647/area-estimation-in-viewpoint-of-map-using-leaflet/18635921#18635921)

Comment: I have tried below code 
this.map.getBounds().contains(e.layer.getLatLng());
and it is returning me true but marker is outof the map.
Please check the image which i have added.

Comment: Well, your image shows that your marker is "on map" (i.e. within the map view port), even though it is not on the tile. If you also want to check that condition, you should define / retrieve the bounds of your tile layer.

Comment: Can this answer be edited to be clearer that this is for Leaflet? The question says Mapbox and I got to the question via Google, only to find out mapbox does not have a #contains method. Hoping to help future devs coming to this question.

Comment: @KyleShevlin thank you for your comment. There might be a confusion between the original [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.0/), which is built on Leaflet, hence has the [`L.LatLngBounds.contains`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.0/l-latlngbounds/) method, and the new [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) (with [its own SO tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapbox-gl-js) BTW), which indeed currently does not. That being said, it might be interesting to have it added, feel free to submit a Feature Request or even a PR on their repo!

Comment: Ahh yes, I am using Mapbox GL on a project. I may submit a PR, I did end up writing my own function for this.

Comment: @KyleShevlin any chance that you post a gist of your code? I basically need to do the same thing.

Comment: @BubbaRaskin within a few hours of this, the spec was changed on me and the feature was ripped out. Fun. The gist of the function was this, get the points of the NE and SW corners of your box. Add 90 to all lats, 180 to all longs (so everything is positive, makes comparisons easier). Then, check if your new point values fall inside the ranges of your new box values. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 8):

I use custom function:

```
function inBounds(point, bounds) {
  var lng = (point.lng - bounds._ne.lng) * (point.lng - bounds._sw.lng) < 0;
  var lat = (point.lat - bounds._ne.lat) * (point.lat - bounds._sw.lat) < 0;
  return lng && lat;
}
```