# Is there any way to count how many visible markers or marker clusters are in the Leaflet map view?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Is there are way to count how many markers (or clusters) are currently visible on the current map view (without scrolling)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269764/check-if-marker-is-in-view-map-mapbox/37270202?r=SearchResults#37270202

Comment: That is to check for a specific marker.  I want to count all the markers that are visible on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplistically you can iterate all the layers on the map, and for those that are a marker, count how many are within the map bounds.

```
function countVisibleMarkers(map) {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var count = 0;

    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            if (bounds.contains(layer.getLatLng())) count++;
         }
    });
    return count;
}
```