# Is it possible to get list of current markers on leaflet Map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Example I have create 6 markers on and after zoom change on the current view of map I have 3 markers So how can I get list of current onscreen markers list after zoom change?

```
 map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
     // want to get current onscreen markers list
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of doing it..... iterate the layers on the map, check each one for being a marker and then for being within the current bounds.

```
function getVisibleMarkers(map) {
    var markerList = [];
    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if ((layer instanceOf L.Marker) && (map.getBounds().contains(layer.getLatLng())){
            markerList.push(layer);
        };
    };
return markerList;
}
```

Comment: It works for me I created a array of markers while creating marker and iterate this array if these markers in current view of map
// create markers array
marker  = L.marker([lat, lang], {icon: greenIcon,}).addTo(mapMarine);
oldMarkerMarine.push(marker);

Comment: // get list of markers in current mapview
function getVisibleMarkers(map) {
        var markerList = [];
        oldMarkerMarine.each(function(mark) {
            if((mark instanceof L.Marker) && 
 map.getBounds().contains(mark.getLatLng())) {
                markerList.push(mark);
            }
        });
        return markerList;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Loop on your 6 Markers.

For each Marker, check if it is within current map view port:
[Check if marker is in view (map) - mapbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269764/check-if-marker-is-in-view-map-mapbox/37270202?r=SearchResults#37270202)